# Applying all templates to a global variable instead of source

Tags: xslt, global-variables, xslt-1.0

I have used a global variable to capture a set of nodes from the source XML. For each node in the source XML I need to check if that node exists in the variable. Is this possible?

The other option is to have all the templates apply to the global variable instead of the source XML. But I don't know if that is possible either.

Given the answer below. If I try to apply the templates to the global variable I get the following code, but it doesn't work. How do I pass the variable on to the rest of the templates and still have the appropriate matches?

```
<xsl:variable name="transformation_result">   
  <ABC>
    <xsl:copy-of select="/ABC/Data"/>
  </ADT>
</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$transformation_result"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="remove_whitespace" match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: It'd be easier to help you if you posted some code with which we could anchor the conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($var)/node()" mode="m2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="m2">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="m2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="remove_whitespace" match="text()" mode="m2">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

where the namespace `exsl` in your stylesheet needs to be declared as `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` then you can process the result of the variable in a second step and remove white space.

Comment: This is good! Definitely helps. If you could take a look at the code above and see where I am going wrong, your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If the variable should select nodes in the input document then it needs to be set up as `<xsl:variable name="transformation_result" select="/ABC/Data"/>`. Your posted approach creates a result tree fragment with a copy of nodes from the input.

Comment: The trouble is this is a simplified version of the variable. The variable will contain many copy-of's and other modifications to the source. I want to trim whitespace from all the nodes in the variable and have the cleaned-up version be my output.

Comment: With your latest explanation I think your question with "a global variable to capture a set of nodes from the source XML" does not describe the scenario correctly as copied nodes and modifications are not nodes form the source. So my generate-id suggestion can't work with nodes from different trees. As for building a variable and processing it in a second step, with XSLT 1.0 that can be done using `exsl:node-set` or similar on a variable with a result tree fragment and then applying templates, perhaps with modes to separate the transformation steps.

Comment: Adding the node-set function did the trick!!! `<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($transformation_result)"/>`